# Largest Step size in Quadratic Interpolation ( Numerical Interpolation )

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Question: The function $f(x) =(1+x)^6$ is to be tabulated at equispaced points in the interval  $[0.1]$ using quadratic interpolation. Find the largest step size that can be used used so that the error $\le 5 × 10^-3$ in magnitude.

Problem: Can we convert a polynomial of degree 6 into degree 2? Is it not going to completely change the result/nature of polynomial. I have solved these kind of problems but there the polynomial that was given was of degree 1 or less then 2 (eg:- $f(x)= \frac{1}{x} $ OR $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$).

Formula Used (for 2 degree polynomial):   $|E|\le \dfrac{h^3M}{(9\sqrt{3})}$

Where: $M= \max_{x \in[a,b]} |f'''(x)| $

$$h= \text{step size}$$

$f'''$ stands for 3rd derivative

Let me know if I missed anything or if further clarification is needed. I kindly request you to review my proposed solution and provide feedback on its accuracy.

My Solution:
[image]

Comment: Please repeat the actual computation, in a rough estimate $h^3\lessapprox 64\cdot 10^{-6}$ gives $h\lessapprox 4\cdot 10^{-2}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your kind assistance in pointing out my error. Upon reviewing my calculations, I have identified the mistake and made the necessary corrections.  Ans  h<= 0.04330